# Android ViewModel for a custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-architecture-components

I would like to refactor my Custom View to use android architecture components. However, I see that

```
ViewModelProviders.of(...)
```

takes only Activity or fragment. Any idea how to make it work? Should I use fragment instead of Custom View?

Comment: @pskink your answer isn't related to my question.

Comment: I have already Custom View and want to refactor it to MVVM using Android Architecture Components.

Comment: My Custom View is complex and has a ton of code, it's not a simple TextView.

Comment: Everything is in the question @pskink. Android ViewModel doesn't work with View, but nevermind, I refactored my View to be a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get obtain a ViewModel instance in View, although it's not recommended. As per [this post](https://sapandiwakar.in/accessing-viewmodel-inside-views-on-android-2/):

> While it is easy enough to obtain the ViewModels inside an Activity or a Fragment, it is not straightforward to obtain this instance inside a View. The main reason behind this is because Views are supposed to be independent of all processing and even if all your logic is inside a ViewModel, the fact that you are accessing that ViewModel inside the View makes it reliant on something that it shouldn't. The recommended way of controlling a View is to pass parameters to it based on the state of the ViewModel from the Fragment or the Activity.

The point is to try to get an Activity from the context:

```
override val activity: FragmentActivity by lazy {  
    try {
        context as FragmentActivity
    } catch (exception: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException("Please ensure that the provided Context is a valid FragmentActivity")
    }
}
override var viewModel = ViewModelProvider(activity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

As mentioned thought, I'd try to avoid this approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()` to retrieve a `ViewModel` from within your custom `View`.

And then implement `DefaultLifecycleObserver` in that view so you can hook onto lifecycle methods.

Those 2 combined should give you all the ViewModel and Scope options you get with `Activity` and `Fragment` implementations`.

### Example kotlin code

Custom View code, here it's based on a `ConstraintLayout` and I've added `KoinViewModelFactory` so that your dependencies can be injected via the constructor. Otherwise just use `ViewModelProvider(owner)`.

```
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.factory.KoinViewModelFactory
import org.koin.core.component.getScopeId
import org.koin.core.qualifier.named
import org.koin.mp.KoinPlatform.getKoin

class MyCustomView : ConstraintLayout, DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private val viewModel by lazy {
        findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()?.let { owner ->
            ViewModelProvider(
                owner,
                KoinViewModelFactory(
                    kClass = MyCustomViewModel::class,
                    scope = getKoin().getOrCreateScope(scopeId = owner.getScopeId(), named(owner.getScopeId())),
                )
            )[MyCustomViewModel::class.java]
        }
    }

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.my_custom_view, this)
        // makes this view lifecycle aware
        (context as? LifecycleOwner)?.lifecycle?.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onCreate(owner)
        // observe changes
        viewModel?.events?.observeNonNull(owner) { handleEvent(it) }
    }

    override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        // other lifecycle methods like this are available...
    }

    fun handleEvent(event: UiEvent) {}
}
```

ViewModel implementation

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent

class MyCustomViewModel(
    private val injectedService: SomeService, // will be injected
) : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {

    val events = MutableLiveData<UiEvent>() // live data example

    fun someAction() {
        events.value = UiEvent.SomeAction
    }

    sealed class UiEvent {
        data object SomeAction : UiEvent()
    }
}
```